# Filtering Issue with DevExpress Wpf GridControl

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0, devexpress, gridcontrol

here my problem: I'm developing an application using DexExpress wpf `GridControl 10.1, c#, Net 4.0` and I use checkbox dropdown lists to filter columns. Now when I set a filter on a column, and then  try to filter on a second one, on the second filter it shows all the values of the column, and not only the visible ones. 
Let me do an example:

> C. A   C. B   C. C
>   1        A       q
>   2        C       a
>   1        B       q
>   2        C       t
>   2        D       f

Noe: if a set on Col. A the filter `"[Col. A] = 2"`, and then I drop down the checklist filter on column B, I see:

> A
>   B
>   C
>   D

while I would see only:

> C
>   D

(as in Excel)... What can I do?

Thanks in advance!

Luigi

Answer (score 0):

The solution is provided by DevExpress support team here: [filter popup](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q243835.aspx)